# ASP.NET MVC - Model not binding on Ajax.BeginForm in partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, model-view-controller, model

I have a partial View *AddOptionPartial* which uses a model *OptionViewModel*.
This partial view is loaded when its parent, *Build* is loaded.
This *Build* view uses the model *BuildViewModel*.

The partial is loaded in using using `@{Html.RenderPartial("AddOptionPartial", new OptionViewModel());}`.

The partial looks like this:

```
@model SurveyService.ViewModels.OptionViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddOption", "Manage", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "handleSavedOptionChoice(data)", HttpMethod = "Post" }))
{ 
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ChoiceText)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ChoiceValue, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ChoiceValue)
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ChoiceValue, 1) True
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ChoiceValue, 0) False
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary active">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ChoiceValue, 2, true) Text
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Create</button>
}
```

As you can see, i am trying to post this form using an Ajax call. The call refers to this function:

```
public ActionResult AddOption(OptionViewModel model)
{
    ***content of function***
}
```

However, when debugging, the model is an OptionViewModel object containing no data.
I can not find a reason for this on SO, can someone please advise?

Comment: Can you show the definition of your OptionViewModel?

Comment: `public class OptionViewModel    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ChoiceText { get; set; }
        public int? ChoiceValue{ get; set; }
    }`

Comment: OptionChoiceVm does not match the OptionViewModel in the view definition. The properties are not the same as those used in the view either.

Comment: I have to be more consistent with my renaming for SO purposes... ;-)

Comment: You are using the same property for the textbox (string?) and for the radio buttons (int). Try adding a different property for each data item.

Comment: Did you try to remove the `HttpMethod = "Post"` in your `Ajax.BeginForm` ? Else, you should decorate your controller method with `[HttpPost]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error in the code found:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ChoiceText)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ChoiceValue, new { @class = "form-control" })

@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ChoiceValue, 1) True
```

Setting multiple values on a single parameter causes that parameter to act like a list, which only creates a ModelState error and will never fill the model.

To anyone who encounters a similar problem in the future: Debug your controller function and have a look at the ModelState in the debugger.

Thanks to everyone who advised.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
       @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddOption", "Manage",null, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "handleSavedOptionChoice(data)", HttpMethod = "Post" }))



            public ActionResult AddOptionChoice([System.Web.Http.FromBody]OptionViewModel model)
            {
                ***content of function***
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When adding `System.Web.Http`, VS informs me that The namespace Http does not exist in the namespace System.Web.
I am using .Net 4.5.2

Comment: in that case pls add and check

Comment: This namespace appears to be part of the Asp.NET Core framework, which i am not using. I cannot freely add frameworks as i am restricted by the company to MVC5.

Answer (score 1):

`@{Html.RenderPartial("AddOptionChoicePartial", new OptionViewModel());}` passes exactly that; a new, presumably empty, `OptionViewModel`.

You should either pass in a pre-populated model (from the parent `BuildViewModel`) like `@{Html.RenderPartial("AddOptionChoicePartial", parentViewModel.SomeModel);}` or construct the View Model from scratch in `AddOptionChoice`.

(Note also that you're calling `"AddOptionChoicePartial"` from `Html.RenderPartial`, but the Controller Action is named `AddOptionChoice`. They should match)

Also, in trying to recreate the model from your comments, you're using ChoiceText and ChoiceValue, which do not match OptionText and OptionValue.

Comment: But the values of the variables of the Option are set by the user in the form right? In the controller action i create a new model and fill it with the user entered data from the viewmodel. (Names of functions fixed in question)

Comment: Update: tried prepopulating the viewmodel:`@{Html.RenderPartial("AddOptionChoicePartial", OptionViewModel {a = "a", b = 1});}`. When posting, the model still contains null values for both

Comment: Ah - I misunderstood the question - I thought you were displaying the form using the Partial called from the parent - it's an obvious one but do you have [HttpPost] attribute on AddOption ?

Comment: Yes, i have that attribute added to AddOption.
Could i have this issue since the child view has a different model than the parent view in which it is rendered?

Comment: @Schmoerff - updated for problem seen in recreating model

Comment: Back at work, naming as supplied in question and comments is now consistent. Still not working though...

Answer (score -1):

Change the parameter name to *data*

```
public ActionResult AddOption(OptionViewModel data)
{
// Do something here
}
```